# How can I reduce the pungent odor of split pea soup?

Tags: soup

I love the soup, but hate how it makes my house smell.

Comment: Is it the smell of the split peas or some other seasoning in the recipe that you find objectionable? (Personally, I think lentil soup has a stronger odor that always smells a little exotic to me).

Comment: is it just peas? what recipe are you using?

Answer (score 2):

Bake bread to go with the soup as you make it.

The smell of bread baking (sourdough in particular!) is usually enough to cut the smell of lentil / split pea / chic pea / fish soups and stews while adding the right elements of savory aroma to make the combined smell almost, if not actually desirable and palatable.

Any good yeasty bread recipe should do the trick. Another thing you can do is bloom some saffron, which mixes delightfully with the smell of split pea soup.

In short, taste your soup as you smell other things. When you hit on winning combinations, they're aromatically complimentary and create a sensory affinity. Many bistros (and bakeries themselves) rely on this technique to lure passers-by.

Answer (score 0):

- Cook with windows open.
- use an exhaust fan.
- Buy it ready-made elsewhere.
- Ask a friend/neighbor/relative for the use of their kitchen. (Possibly in exchange for goods/services/money)